# Difference between @warn_unqualified_access and @warn_unused_result?

Tags: swift

Can anyone explain with one example of  `warn_unqualified_access` and `warn_unused_result`

Comment: I've found this article very useful for understanding `@warn_unqualified_access`
https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/warn_unqualified_access/

Answer (score 42):

## `@warn_unused_result`

Suppose you have an array representing a deck of cards:

```
var deck: [Card] = standardDeck.shuffled()
```

You want to write a function to deal a card to a player. You want to pull the “top” card from the deck, add it to the player's hand, and remove it from the deck:

```
func dealCard(to player: Player) {
    guard let card = deck.last else { fatalError("Ran out of cards") }
    player.hand.append(card)
    deck.dropLast()
}
```

When you test your app, you are puzzled. All your players' hands are filled with copies of the same card.

Being new to Swift, you think `dropLast` modifies `deck` by removing its last element. Sadly, you are mistaken. It returns a **new** array containing all but the last element of `deck`. (Technically it returns an `ArraySlice`.)

The compiler and the standard library have conspired to help you figure out the problem. The `dropLast` function is annotated with `@warn_unused_result`, so Xcode shows you a warning on the `dropLast` call:

```
.../Cards.swift:85:10: Result of call to 'dropLast()' is unused
```

Seeing the warning, you decide to option-click on `dropLast` and read the documentation, which tells you what `dropLast` does (returns a new array), and you realize you need to change the line to this:

```
    deck.removeLast()
```

Many, many functions, in the Swift standard library and in other libraries, are useful mainly for what they return. Ignoring the returned value of one of these functions is usually an error, so Swift makes it easy for the library author to warn the user about this behavior. In fact, [Swift will probably soon be modified](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.swift.evolution/12377) to apply `@warn_unused_result` by default, and to use a new `@discardableResult` attribute on the function to suppress the warning.

## `@warn_unqualified_access`

You were so successful with your awesome card game on iOS that you've decided to port it to Mac OS X. On Mac OS X, you use `NSView` instead of `UIView` to show things on the screen. You're trying to figure out why your custom `CardView` is drawing itself incorrectly, so you want to call Swift's standard `print` function in `drawRect:`

```
class CardView: NSView {

    var card: Card

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        print("Drawing \(card)")

        // drawing code here...
    }

    // rest of CardView here...
}
```

When you run your app, you're surprised to find that it pops up the print dialog! What's going on? The compiler and `NSView` have conspired to help you figure out the problem. The `NSView.print` function is annotated with `@warn_unqualified_access`, so Xcode shows you a warning on the `print` call:

```
.../CardView.swift:95:9: Use of 'print' treated as a reference to instance method in class 'NSView'
```

Seeing the warning, you option-click on `print` and read the documentation. You learn that `NSView` has its own `print` method, which lets the user print the contents of the view onto paper. How droll! Now you realize you need to change the call to explicitly use Swift's `print` function like this:

```
        Swift.print("Drawing \(card)")
```

(It is virtually impossible to develop for Mac OS X in Swift without running into this particular case. Repeatedly.)

This sort of problem is much less common than the other problem of ignoring a function's result. `NSView.print` is the only case that I can recall running into.

Comment: Nice explanation! The reasoning behind the use of those attributes is just as important as their effect. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Consider the following example:

```
class C { 
   @warn_unqualified_access func foo(x: Int) -> Int { return x } 
   @warn_unused_result func bar(x: Int) -> Int { return foo(x) } 
 } 

func main() {
  let c = C()
  c.foo(1)
  c.bar(1)
}

main()
```

This generates two warnings.

One in `C.foo()`:

> warning: use of 'foo' treated as a reference to instance method in class 'C'
>            use 'self.' to silence this warning

This is because I declared `foo` `as @warn_unqualified_access`, so it means the compiler wants me to explicitly refer to the object when accessing said member. This is because - for example - calling `print` in a subclass of `NSView` conflicts between `Swift.print` and `NSView.print`

The second warning is generated in `main()`, when calling bar:

> warning: result of call to 'bar' is unused c.bar(1)

This is because I am calling `bar()`, declared as `@warn_unused_result`, and then discarding its result. This is useful, for example, in methods which return you a new value but have no side effects. If you choose to ignore the new value, you essentially wasted work. The compiler can warn you to point that out.